# Structure of an HTML post Request vs Django HTML Post Request

Tags: html, django, forms, django-templates

I have the following HTML form code which I am trying to translate to Django Templating Language.

```
<form action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST"><input type=hidden name="oid" value="00D280000016jv0">
    <input type=hidden name="retURL" value="https://url/form/">
    <label for="first_name">First Name</label><input id="first_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20"
        type="text" /><br>
    <label for="last_name">Last Name</label><input id="last_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20"
        type="text" /><br>
    <label for="email">Email</label><input id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    <label for="phone">Phone</label><input id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>
    </select><br><input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

I've looked at Django Templating Tutorials but I'm unable to translate this. What is the Django equivalent of this code?

Comment: @Razenstein please read again

Answer (score 0):

you could create a model based on this such

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import MaxValueValidator

class MyModel(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField( max_length=254)
    phone = models.PositiveIntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(999999)])
```

views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import CreateView
from .models import MyModel
from . forms import Myform

class MyView(CreateView):
    model = MyModel
    form_class  = MyForm
    template_name = 'mytemplate.html'
    success_url = "https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8"
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from .models import MyModel

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta():
        model = MyModel
        fields='__all__'
```

urls.py:

```
from .views import MyView

urlpatterns = [
    path('create/', MyView.as_view(), name='create'),
]
```

HTML template

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {%csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_p}}
</form>
```

as you see a whole project, because this will give you the possibility to store your data, and then you update it delete it add new one by adding functions to views as you mentioned in your question